# JSP form with validation in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm trying to use JSP and servlets to perform form processing according to the principles of separating logic from presentation, but it seems rather counterintuitive for the moment.

So far, I have a simple JSP page with a form and a jsp:usebean to get the request parameter into a java object.
I use JST 'if' to check the calling method. If it is GET, I display the page, and if it is POST, I forward to a validating servlet.

The idea is that the servlet performs processing, then redirects to the form whenever the data is not correct.

The problem is, if the servlet process post, and then redirects to the form, that form will call the servlet again in an infinite loop, so I need to change the request method to "GET" before forwarding.

Another possibly consist in calling a servlet first, then calling the JSP file as a view. But the  is a neat feature, and doing it in a servlet requieres instanciating the object manually with calls to request.getParameter(), which also implies a lot of duplication wrt. to the parameter names, hence the necessity of using the JSP first. I could use a JSP for , then forwarding to the servlet, then to the "view" JSP, but that seem a bit tedious for a single "feature" of JSP. So despite much effort, I'm still looking for a neat solution.

How do people apply the principles of "no code in JSP" in practice, while maintaining the "no code duplication" principles ? Is it possible to change the request method when forwarding ? Is it possible to emulate  in Java code ? Is the JSP "way" of accomplishing this simple use case just ugly by modern standards ? I may use a lot of workarounds, but I'm trying to stick as much as possible to the standards.

Answer (score 1):

Use the servlet as a *controller*.  Meaning, the user never sees the .jsp extension or any other mapped url of the JSP.  User is always sent to the servlet's URL.  Then the servlet forwards to the JSP as needed. In fact, you will want to place your jsp in `WEB-INF` to make it impossible for the user to get there any other way than by the controller (i.e. the servlet).

Forward here is used in its proper technical sense, meaning it passes execution to the JSP *in the background* but the servlet's URL stays in the address bar (which is very different from a redirect).  This ensures that if the user hits refresh, the servlet is still controlling the flow of execution.

Ok. Now for your logic:

If the request is POST and validation is Ok then the servlet processes it.

If validation fails or the request is GET, the servlet forwards to the JSP.

You will have to get rid of jsp:useBean as its not compatible with servlets. See the bottom of the [servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

As to the code duplication, I guess you mean calling `request.getParameter()` in the servlet and then moving the same into `request.setAttribute()` then reading the attributes in the JSP after the forward.  Well, if you are really using a bean, you should be putting all your parameters into the bean and setting the bean into `request.setAttribute()` so you would not be reading the parameters from the same place anymore in the JSP since you'll be looking at the bean not the request parameters....so its not code duplication.  (This also explains what you replace the obsolete jsp:useBean with.)

So lets take this example from the servlet's info page. In the servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Preprocess request: load list of products for display in JSP.
    List<Product> products = productService.list();
    request.setAttribute("products", products);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/products.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

In the JSP:

```
       <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
            <tr>
                <td>${product.id}</td>
                <td><c:out value="${product.name}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${product.description}" /></td>
                <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${product.price}" type="currency" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

See how the servlet is creating an object named `products` and placing it in the request attribute?  You would do the same thing, but here instead of a list it would be whatever type your bean is.  And the same when accessing it in EL in the JSP: you'd be accessing your bean that way: `request.setAttribute("myBean", beanObj);` in servlet and `${myBean.memberName}` in JSP.